# Trouble with positioning of nvd3 pie charts

Tags: nvd3.js

I have two *nvd3 pie charts* in my page and when I try to position them with 
the following code,only the first one is getting replaced. The second one seems to have no effect.
This is the code I used

```
d3.select(".nv-pieWrap")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,-35)");
```

This is taken in the first graph, but for the second pie chart,the positioning is not applied, when I checked with *Firebug*.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Just try d3.selectAll(".nv-pieWrap").attr("transform", "translate(0,-35)");

Comment: @ovvn it worked!
can you post it as answer?..also can you explain what made this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to select all pie charts on the page, you'll need to use d3.selectAll as follows

```
 d3.selectAll(".nv-pieWrap")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0,-35)");
```

According to d3 API reference:

> A selection is an array of elements pulled from the current document.
>   ...
>   ...
>   After selecting elements, you apply operators to them to do stuff. These operators can get or set attributes, styles, properties, HTML and text content. Attribute values and such are specified as either constants or functions; the latter are evaluated for each element.

You can find more at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections